# how to edit $woo_options['woo_featured_height'

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a old wordpress site that is defining some CSS using this code:

```
$fixed_height = ' style="height: ' . $woo_options['woo_featured_height'] . 'px;"';
<div class="slide <?php echo $css_class; ?>"<?php echo $fixed_height; ?>>
```

I cannot figure out where the `$woo_options['woo_featured_height']` is defined. I have searched the entire codebase and there is no such value.

Comment: `$woo_options` are similar to `$wp_options` and can be used by any theme/plugin. The `$woo_options['woo_featured_height']` value is stored in db. Check [official guide](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/adding-theme-options/) for `$woo_options`

Answer (score 0):

That's a woocommerce options array and most likely the option you are looking for comes from a database table and won't exists in your codebase.  See this [link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/adding-theme-options/) for more information.